# What do I do if the saddles on my bridge are already touching the bridge but I want to raise my action?

Tags: electric-guitar, intonation, setup, bridge

I want to raise the action a tad of my Schecter Omen Extreme 6, because there is a bit of fret buzz on the 5th fret 1st string, and a bit around the higher frets as well (same string). But I know that if you raise the action, your intonation will go out of whack and I know that you have to raise it to sharpen it, so what do I do if I need to raise it but the saddles are already touching the bridge and can't go any further?

Also tell me if any more pictures or information is needed and I will update it asap.[image]

Comment: In that photo, is the neck of the guitar at the top of the photo or the bottom?

Comment: The neck is at the top.

Comment: That setup looks very wrong to me.  Are you absolutely sure your neck isn't bowed, either forwards or back?  Ot have you changed the guitar over to a very heavy string gauge?  (At this stage I'm just looking for reasons why it's gone so wrong.)

Comment: @Andy - I very much doubt that the intonation is correctly set. I've never seen saddles in a row like those - unless the guitar's come to me for setting up!

Comment: The intonation isn't the problem. It's the fret buzz. The gauge has been standard 10 always, I'll have to check the neck though. Yea, I took it in to get "set up", waste of money and time I'd say.

Comment: Daniel, I think @Tim has it right when he suggests you've been adjusting the intonation by mistake.  The two large screws adjust the bridge height, though how depends on your model.  The six small ones only adjust intonation.  Does that solve the problem?

Comment: I didn't put the intonation like that, and haven't adjusted the action yet, but when I do I'll use the two large screws. It's strange lots of people have been saying the intonation set up is wrong but when I play 12th fret harmonic and the 12th fret note, it's the same. The intonation is a tad questionable around the 19th and 20th fret though. Also silly question, but you do have to loosen the strings while adjusting the action right? Otherwise the strings would break?

Comment: I've never adjusted one of those - but yes loosen or possibly remove strings first. (Sorry about the intonation comments, I just assumed from the appearance it was set wrong or the bridge was in the wrong place.) However the intonation will probably drift further, so you can reverse the saddles as Tim's main answer. Also check neck straightness and a slight neck relief because **something** doesn't look right.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rJvuDCO.png Check that out, it's very pixilated but you can still make out the screws are supposed to be facing the nut (that's taken from the picture Schecter uses for the same model on their site). Now when I swap the bridge and give it some strings, because the intonation is going to be at the opposite end it will throw it out a lot wont it? What the best way to check that it's out and how precise to I have to be when adjusting it, like very little turns with a screw driver? Quarter tuns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unscrew a saddle so that the screw comes out completely. Turn the saddle through 180 degrees, and replace. It'll give another 2 or 3 mm of adjustment. The intonation looks a little out to me, as B strings are usually longer than the 1st and 3rd.To raise the action, use the two screws at either side of the bridge. Moving saddles tends to change the intonation rather than the string height.

Comment: Intonation isn't 'raised or lowered'. It's adjusted. The length of each string needs to be adjusted, there are answers on how to do it on this site. If the saddle is at the bridge end, and cannot move any closer to the nut ( to shorten the string more), then by turning the triangular saddle round, the tip of it, which the string goes over, will be closer to the nut.

Comment: Tacking the saddles out of the bridge should not be done. The bridge is on backwards.

Answer (score 0):

...or...

Simple unstring, pull up the bridge (nothing holds it) and rotate 180 degree and put down. As I see current the nut in high E is *wide* enough to fit even the low E string. I risk the hypothesis that *now* the bridge is (accidentally) rotated compared to the factory at some past repair action.

You win:

- All your saddles will rotated.
- One extra millimeter for all strings
- your screws will be accessed from neck/pickup side which may (or may not) convenient than current opposite side